# JUnit issue when trying to create an object that has a constructor calling to a static method

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am writing JUnit test to verify some methods.

1. I am creating an object within the test class.
2. Constructor calls to to a static method on a different class.
3. The returning object should be a mocked one.

E.g.:

```
public class Test {
    private Red r;

    @Before
    public setUp() {
        Shape shape = new Shape();
    }

}

public class Shape {
    String t;

    Shape() {
        Red b = Box.getBoxes();
        t = b.getThis();
    }
}

public class Box {
    static Red r;

    public static Red getReds() {
        return r;
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your code is not complete and it doesn't compile. Please provide all classes and error message that you are getting.

Comment: To mock static methods, I would suggest having a look at PowerMock(ito) which can do exactly that. With it, you could mock your Box.getBoxes() call and return anything you like, including a mock object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to mock this functionality using PowerMockito API.

1.To get Red object as a mocked one

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Box.class);
Second mockedRed= PowerMockito.mock(Red.class);
            PowerMockito.when( Box.class).getReds().thenReturn(mockedRed);
```

You need to use Powermockito runner and need to add required test classes (comma separated ) which are required to be mocked by powermock API .

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Box.class,Red.class})
class Test{
// your testing code

}
```